# How to use Xpath 'contains()' function to locate a Web element in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2, xpath

I am a beginner in learning Selenium WebDriver and XPath. I am trying to get the "`<td>`" Element of the Nested Table which Contains string '7-8-9.' Following is the HTML page code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border = "2">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>
    <table border = 1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1-2-3</td>
    <td>4-5-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>7-8-9</td>
    <td>10-11-12</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this the test code :

```
WebElement  cell3 =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[contains(text() , '1-2-3'))]"));

    System.out.println(cell3.getText());
```

Please help!
thanks

Comment: What issue do you getting??

Comment: What is your test code returning?

Comment: @tester23 are you satisfied with saifur's answer?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't want the `xpath` to do a lot of works. So, be little bit more considerate when you the write `xpath`
You don't need to walk down the whole hierarchy to find the element with `xpath`. Relative xpath would be enough for `selenium`. Read [this](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/)

```
//tbody//td[contains(text(),'1-2-3')]
```

Comment: or even better, try not use xpath, and use IDs or names. Faster and less brittle. Ask your developers to add ID to any element.

Comment: @PeterMasiar This is a `Web Table` you know. So `ids` or `names` are always not an option

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty method that will be fragile and perform poorly, but will allow you to get your test working,  open the page in Firefox, open the development tools, find the element in the source viewer, right click, and there should be an option to create an XPath query.

Just noticed the "contains" in the question, if that's important then ignore this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use xpath only if you don't have

- id
- classname
- tagname

Use *contains* in xpath:

- For Android:

  ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@id,'dv-textbox-label-SubList')]");
  ```
- For iOS:

  ```
  iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAStaticText[contains(@name,'MOBDishwasher')]"));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

xpath:

```
//td[contains(text(),'1-2-3')]
```

css:

```
td:contains('1-2-3')
```

Better would be an attribute (id, class, name etc.) in the element and then for example:

xpath:

```
//td[@id='123-value']
```

or css:

```
td#123-value
```